# Using CKReference with CKShare

Tags: ios, cloudkit, ckreference

I am trying to share a parent CKRecord using CKShare. The parent CKRecord has other child records that have CKReferences linked to parent CKRecord.  All is fine and the receiver can fetch the parent record, but I can't seem to access the child records using CKQuery/CKQueryOperation.

When the owner fetches the parent record (without using the CKShare link), he is able to fetch the child record using the same method as above. I'd really like some help with this.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You said you "can't seem to access the child records" - what specifically happens when you try it?

Comment: My bad it finally seems like it works, but the problem is now that I can't seem to fetch all the CKReferenced records (over 500) using ckqueryoperation.